# console shows "unknown operand" from a if statement

Tags: shell, embedded-linux, uclinux

I'm trying to script an automatic md5sum check for my embedded system running uClinux.
The script is generated on my computer as well as the tar file I want to check.

The script goes like this :

```
#!/bin/sh
filename='My_File'
md5='d4deeac6f655ee5d4b9ec150fc6957a5'

if test ! -e $filename.tar
then
    echo Update file does not exist
    exit 1
fi  

if [ -z `md5sum "$filename.tar" | grep $md5` ]
then
    echo 'md5sum is not correct'
    exit 1
else
    echo 'md5sum is correct'
fi  

tar -xvf "$filename.tar"
[...]
```

The md5sum check run as expected, i-e the script stops when the checksum is wrong and executes to the end otherwise. But when the checksum is correct, I get this message from the console :

```
[: My_File.tar: unknown operand
```

I don't understand why I get this, and I think this is not accurate to let my script like this. Can someone explain me what's the shell is doing and how to get rid of this message ?

Thanks

Comment: @rkta, tks for the tips, however my problem lies in the "IF" line with md5sum.

Comment: OR learn to use http://shellcheck.net **before** you post your code here ;-) . When you use shellcheck, you need to include a proper "she-bang" line as the first line, usually `#!/bin/bash` . AND avoid the top 10 shell script beginner mistakes by reading https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info multiple times. Good luck.

Comment: Please remember that I'm running an embedded system with uClinux which is very limited. Changing the first line to `#!/bin/bash` make the script unexecutable, actually `bash` is not present in `/bin`. I tried adding quotes but the problem is still here. Thanks for your advices anyway, it tought me a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote the output of `md5sum` so it's not split into multiple words. `-z` only expects one operand.

```
if [ -z "`md5sum "$filename.tar" | grep $md5`" ]
```

While we're here, might as well switch to the nicer `$(...)` syntax.

```
if [ -z "$(md5sum "$filename.tar" | grep $md5)" ]
```

Comment: Thks for the solution. In my case, the `$(...)` solution doesn't work. My embedded system must be too old/small to get this feature. The first line works fine